# Writing extended file attributes works over SMB but not locally

Tags: smb, synology, xattr

I have a node program that writes extended attributes to files (fs-xattr). This works from a remote machine connected over SMB but if I try to run the command on the machine itself it says extended attributes are not enabled.

How is SMB able to do this? Maybe it has a fallback?

**Specifics**

- The machine that I need extended attributes on is a Synology
  RS2414rp+ DSM 6.2.
- From macos if I connect over SMB I can write and
  read extended file attributes.
- If I ssh into the Synology box I cannot write extended attributes to files
- fstab on the Synology does not have user_xattr on the volume

**Secondary Question**

I cannot find a clear answer on how to enable user_xattr on a Synology box. I'd like to understand the first question but I believe enabling user_xattr will also solve my problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Curious if you ever found out more about this? I have the same questions about support for extended attributes on Synology boxes. A [related question](https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/1/post/125222) was posed on a Synology forum about 2 years ago.

Comment: @mhucka - No, unfortunately, I never found a good answer.